# What to do after ubuntu remounts my filesystem in read/write mode?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates, mount, crash

Warning: Total noob. 
So, I tried to upgrade my version of Ubuntu, as prompted, but I accidentally restarted too early and everything just went horribly. Ubuntu will load to my login screen fine, but when I attempt to log in a bunch of code flashes across the screen and I am brought back to the login screen. I tried using the root session and typing the command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

it then displays some information about mounting, but I'm not sure if its relevant. The only thing it appears to do is make the graphics on my login screen all messed up. From the recovery mode menu, if I select the fail safe boot option or the fix errors boot option it displays: "Continuing will remount your/filesystem in read/write mode and mount any other filesystem defined in /etc/fstab. Do you wish to continue?" I click yes and it says:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda6: clean, 682207/2375680 files, 3538696/9496320 blocks
```

I have tried to type commands like `mount -o remount,rw /`. Nothing ever works out though. I really have no idea what the next step is supposed to be...How do I fix my computer? Sorry if I didn't provide the necessary info, I don't really know what I even need to know.

My system is a dual boot with windows 7 BTW, that seems to be somewhat important.

Comment: As a first step, if you can get to a root shell and mount it rw, run `dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are novice Ubuntu user, then I would recommend fresh installation of current Ubuntu version. It takes far less time and risk than trying to repair current state of your system. Just remember to make backup of your important files. If you are not able to boot into Ubuntu, then boot from Ubuntu Live DVD (that one you installed Ubuntu from). In Live DVD environment all existing partitions are mounted automatically, so you can copy your files to USB pendrive or Windows partition.